# What part is this?

Tags: identification

Anyone as any idea what part this is? Or even what exactly is this supposed to do in a circuit?

It's part of a relay circuit.

[image]

Comment: Please provide context (type of device, partial reverse engineered schematics i.e. probably used together with). Does it have some other side? It kinda looks like a bunch of precision resistors on ceramic in that small resolution

Comment: It looks like a crappy picture.

Comment: Picture sucks. The part could be a transformer core.

Comment: Updated picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a laser trimed resistor array. Sometimes known as a "hybrid". It's used where you need high precision resistors. Less common these days except in specialized equipment.

EDIT: From your new pictures, it looks like it's trimmed to 680 kohm.